# How to write text on a image in php?

Tags: php, image, text

> **Image is not showing,not even the text.I'm not able to find the error.Is there any need of adding extra plugins or library files in it??**

```
   <?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'typesimp.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "Hello World!!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the content type?

```
//Set the Content Type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```